# Powermock error mock object injected using spring when mocking static object

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock, powermock

I am using PowerMock easy mock to mock static method of a class. I have two test cases written, which if I run independently run fine, but give me an error while running simultaneously.

CarTest:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ ServiceCaller.class })
public class CarTest {

  ServiceCaller           mockServiceCallerObjectToReturn;

  public CarTest() {
    PowerMock.mockStaticPartial(ServiceCaller.class, "getInstance");
    mockServiceCallerObjectToReturn = PowerMock.createMock(ServiceCaller.class);
    EasyMock.expect(ServiceCaller.getInstance()).andReturn(mockServiceCallerObjectToReturn);
  }

  @Test
  public void test1() throws IOException {
    PowerMock.reset(mockServiceCallerObjectToReturn);
    PowerMock.reset(ServiceCaller.class);

    EasyMock.expect(ServiceCaller.getInstance()).andReturn(mockServiceCallerObjectToReturn);

    EasyMock.expect(mockServiceCallerObjectToReturn.checkValidity("testDriver")).andReturn(false);

    PowerMock.replay(mockServiceCallerObjectToReturn);
    PowerMock.replay(ServiceCaller.class);

    Car car = CarFactory.getInstance().getCar();
    boolean canDrive = car.drive("testDriver");
    Assert.assertEquals(canDrive, false);

    PowerMock.verify(mockServiceCallerObjectToReturn);
    PowerMock.verify(ServiceCaller.class);
  }

  @Test
  public void test2() throws IOException {
    PowerMock.reset(mockServiceCallerObjectToReturn);
    PowerMock.reset(ServiceCaller.class);

    EasyMock.expect(ServiceCaller.getInstance()).andReturn(mockServiceCallerObjectToReturn);

    EasyMock.expect(mockServiceCallerObjectToReturn.checkValidity("testDriver")).andReturn(false);

    PowerMock.replay(mockServiceCallerObjectToReturn);
    PowerMock.replay(ServiceCaller.class);

    Car car = CarFactory.getInstance().getCar();
    boolean canDrive = car.drive("testDriver");
    Assert.assertEquals(canDrive, false);

    PowerMock.verify(mockServiceCallerObjectToReturn);
    PowerMock.verify(ServiceCaller.class);
  }
}
```

CarFactory:

```
public class CarFactory {    
  private static final String               CAR_SPRING_CONTEXT_XML = "/com/archit/mock/spring-config/CarSpringContext.xml";    
  protected static final ApplicationContext CONTEXT                = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { CAR_SPRING_CONTEXT_XML });    
  private static final CarFactory           INSTANCE               = new CarFactory();    
  public static CarFactory getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
  }    
  public Car getCar() {
    return CONTEXT.getBean("car", Car.class);
  }    
}
```

Car:

```
package com.archit.mock;
public class Car {
  private final ServiceCaller        serviceCaller;
  public Car(final ServiceCallerFactory serviceCallerFactory) {
    this.serviceCaller = serviceCallerFactory.getServiceCaller();
  }
  public boolean drive(final String driver) {
    return (serviceCaller.checkValidity(driver));
  }
}
```

ServiceCaller:

```
package com.archit.mock;
public class ServiceCaller {
  private static class ServiceCallerHolder {
    private static ServiceCaller INSTANCE = new ServiceCaller();
  }
  public static ServiceCaller getInstance() {
    return ServiceCallerHolder.INSTANCE;
  }
  public boolean checkValidity(final String x) {
    // Do some call
    throw new IllegalStateException("This should have been mocked");
  }
}
```

ServiceCallerFactory:

```
package com.archit.mock;
public class ServiceCallerFactory {
  public ServiceCaller getServiceCaller() {
    return ServiceCaller.getInstance();
  }
}
```

Spring Config:

```
<bean name="car" class="com.archit.mock.Car">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="serviceCallerFactory" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean name="serviceCallerFactory" class="com.archit.mock.ServiceCallerFactory" />
```

Error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call ServiceCaller.checkValidity("testDriver"):
    ServiceCaller.checkValidity("testDriver"): expected: 1, actual: 2
  at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:44)
  at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:85)
  at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:94)
  at com.archit.mock.ServiceCaller$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9848ad9e.checkValidity(<generated>)
  at com.archit.mock.Car.drive(Car.java:12)
  at com.archit.mock.CarTest.test2(CarTest.java:60)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:312)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:296)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:284)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:209)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:148)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:102)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:42)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Other Observations:

- Making the object scope as prototype in spring config works fine.
- Both tests when run individually work fine.
- Based on above 2, It seems to be a problem with re-setting the mocks.

Answer (score 1):

I've found it easier with mocks to have them start as new objects each time the tests are run.  You can achieve this by having all your mock objects at the top as private variables, using the Mockito.Mock annotation:

```
@Mock
private MockOneClass mockOne;
...
@Mock
private MockNClass mockN;
```

Then using the JUnit Before annotation, create a setup function of some sort that initializes all the mock objects:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    // initialize all the @Mock objects
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

This way, before each test runs you get a new Mock created, which you can then apply any amount of `expects` and functionality to, without having to worry about clearing out any old mocking done in a previous test.  If you have any Mock that you know will provide some specific functionality (static singleton mock `getInstance` calls for example) can be called in this `setup` function to help keep the tests cleaner of Mock resetting.

I have some test that has 10+ tests all run in a row that uses this framework.  Not only does it make it a lot easier to read, but it makes setting up tests from scratch really fast.  Being able to copy old mock setups in Tests and remove/change certain pieces is so much easier then having to upkeep every mock object every test, which just doesn't extend well once you start getting more tests.